# how to manipulate component state based on localstorage before component render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, browser

I'm trying to build a browser extension which runs a countdown timer. Now browser extensions reloads every time the user closes and opens the popup window again. Hence I have used localStorage to keep track of the state values.

**Problem**: Let's say I close the popup window when the timer was at `10:00`. After 30 seconds, when I open the popup window, the timer will for a second show `10:00` and then it would change to `09:30` and the countdown will begin.

I know it is happening because the timer is reading the initial values from the localStorage after every render but I can't figure out the way to directly show the current timer state.
Would someone please suggest how do I fix this?
Here is the relevant code:

```
const FocusModeView2 = (props) => {
  let minsLeftLocal = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("minsLeft"));
  let secsLeftLocal = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("secsLeft"));

  const [minsLeft, setMinsLeft] = useState(minsLeftLocal);
  const [secsLeft, setSecsLeft] = useState(secsLeftLocal);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

  const styles = focusModeView2Styles(progress);

  useEffect(() => {
    
    let startTime = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("startTime"));
    let focusPeriod = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("focusPeriod"));
    let timeLength = focusPeriod * 60 * 1000; // in milliseconds
    let timerLengthInSecs = props.focusPeriod * 60;
    let endTime = startTime + timeLength;
    let timer = setInterval(() => {
      let currentTime = Date.now();
      let newMinsLeft = Math.floor((endTime - currentTime) / (1000 * 60));
      let newSecsLeft = Math.round(((endTime - currentTime) / 1000) % 60);
      newSecsLeft = newSecsLeft === 60 ? 0 : newSecsLeft;
      let totalSecsLeft = newMinsLeft * 60 + newSecsLeft;
      setMinsLeft(newMinsLeft);
      setSecsLeft(newSecsLeft);

      localStorage.setItem("minsLeft", newMinsLeft);
      localStorage.setItem("secsLeft", newSecsLeft);
      let currentProgress =
        ((timerLengthInSecs - totalSecsLeft) / timerLengthInSecs) * 360;
      setProgress(currentProgress);

      if (newMinsLeft <= 0 && newSecsLeft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        props.resetTimer();
      }
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.timer}>
        {minsLeft < 10 ? `0${minsLeft}` : minsLeft} :{" "}
        {secsLeft < 10 ? `0${secsLeft}` : secsLeft}
      </div>
      <div className={styles.progressBar}></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FocusModeView2;
```

Here's the github repo for the same:https://github.com/pragyes31/focus-sutra

Answer (score 0):

You can use `componentWillMount` to set the timer before rendering it.

Comment: I am using functional component. Any way to achieve this in functional component?

Comment: I see you are using useState() which is the answer for functional components. However, you are not updating the state correctly, but only updating the localStorage which is then passed to state as default value. You need to use setState(localStorage...)